# Updating celery conf at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have a flask app running with celery as worker backend.

I load my configuration variables via flask and give them to celery which works just fine.

```
flask_app.config.from_object(config)
celery.conf.update(flask_app.config)
```

There is an option in my app to update a setting which also needs to be applied to celery at run-time, none of my tries seem to permanently save the config. [Here is the documention](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#configuration)

```
from celery import current_app
current_app.conf.update(new_settings)
```

or

```
from celery import current_app
current_app.conf['SOME_SETTING'] = new_settings['SOME_SETTING']
```

In both tries 'SOME_SETTING' is correctly updated in the current_app during the update task but when making a new task the config is still it's original value and not the new one.

I cannot find anything about this issue online, any help or indication in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Coming a bit late, hope this still helps

If there aren't many new settings to update, try modify them directly

```py
current_app.conf.broker_url = new_settings["BROKER_URL"]
current_app.conf.result_backend = new_settings["CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND"]
```

or based on my pure guessing, you have some mismatched naming in `flask_app.config`

Celery changed some setting name to lower case in version 4, see [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.4.6/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings)